# Android Apps Sometimes take too long to load

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created a new app that have several background operations at start. 
If there are no other apps running, it takes 5-6 second to load the app. 
However if other apps are opened, the loading time will be much longer and it will take 15-20 seconds to load... Does any one know the reasons behind?

Comment: If they are non-UI components, have you considered pushing them into a background service?

Comment: if you are using virtual device than it will depend on the processor most probably and your pc performance

Answer (score 1):

Every app is going to take a while to start up, but several seconds seems like a long time, depending on how old the device is. You should definitely try and get those long-running operations off the UI thread.

If you're not doing anything that needs to touch the UI, you could try something like this:

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do your long-running operations here.
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Or, if you need to do things that touch UI components, you could use AsyncTasks:

```
private class LongRunningTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(String... data) {
         //Do your long-running operations here.
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //Update a UI element to show the results
     }
 }
```